# Build dynamic INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to use variable in my Insert query (ex. $table) instead of 'categories' witch is the name of my table. I've read something about 'prepare', but don't get it at all how can I do it with my code. Can someone help my with this issue?

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO categories (name, description) VALUES ("' . $_POST['name'] . '", "' .     $_POST['description'] . '")';
```

The table name will come as one parameter of function if does it matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a variable again:

```
$table_name = 'categories';//or other table
$sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table_name .' (name, description) VALUES ("' . $_POST['name'] . '", "' .     $_POST['description'] . '")';
```

Comment: I think It will work only if all tables have same columns(name).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do something like this:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["description"]);

$query = "INSERT INTO {$table_name} (";
$query .= "name, description";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query .= " '{$menu}', '{$description}' ";
$query .= ")";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) just for security sake, it just escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.